# understand the terraform for OCI

Tags: terraform, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I have 3 questions here:

I have created terraform form scripts in Oracle Cloud Infrastructure to build the instance and other resources. But I am not able to get any script for route table configuration and service in network script. So i have made them manual. my current table has only the resource name, rest all configuration is blank. So i need help in getting a properly supported script for OCI to create route table with configuration.

As i did such things manually, i am not able to give terraform apply after doing some changes in the script, as terraform apply will delete all the rules which i created manually. So is it mandatory to give terraform apply every time when i change the script? or can i enter the config manually and simultaneously match that in the terraform script so that everything is intact?

After every terraform changes i could see 2 files is getting enlarge (terraform.tfstate, terraform.tfstate.backup) what are these two files? if that is a backup file, then how will it help me to restore if i mess up in my configuration?

Answer (score 0):

In Terraform, the configuration script is always the source of truth. When you apply a configuration; Terraform will favor the settings of that configuration and override any changes that were manually done outside of Terraform.

To make sure your manual changes are not overwritten, you should make sure the configuration always matches the manual changes. One way to import manual resources into your configuration is using "terraform import" (see https://www.terraform.io/docs/import/index.html).

The terraform.tfstate and terraform.tfstate.backup files are used by Terraform to keep track of the latest state of the resources that Terraform has created. These files are used to help Terraform determine whether you configuration script has drifted from the state; so it knows how to apply your configuration script. To my knowledge, these state files are not intended to be backup files if you mess up your configuration. (see https://www.terraform.io/docs/state/index.html)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example for a route table resource in Terraform config file:

```
resource "oci_core_route_table" "webserver-rt" {
    compartment_id = "${var.compartment_ocid}"
    vcn_id = "${oci_core_virtual_network.oci-vcn.id}"
    display_name = "webserver-rt"
    route_rules = [{
        destination = "0.0.0.0/0"
        network_entity_id = "${oci_core_internet_gateway.internet-gateway.id}"
    }]
}
```

You may find more details here: https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-oci/blob/master/docs/examples/networking/route_table/route_table.tf